# Wagtail: How to perform site-wide search with custom SearchField declarations in subclassed pages?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-search

I'm using the built-in Wagtail search with POSTGRES backend. I don't want to go to Elastic Search as this would be overkill for the site concerned.

The problem I'm hitting and can't find any info on is how to perform a site-wide search that includes all the search fields declared in the subclassed pages.

For example:

```
class SEOPage(Page):
....
    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('summary'),
    ]

class BlogDetailPage(SEOPage):
....
    search_fields = SEOPage.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]
```

But if do something like

```
Page.objects.search("findme")
```

or even

```
Page.objects.specific().search("findme")
```

then neither the summary or body fields are searched because they don't exist at the Page model level.

Is there any way to perform a site wide search that includes all the SearchField's in the site?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt Westcott, the solution was to use the POSTGRES backend:
https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/postgres_search.html

It's very easy to add multi-language support using this as well.